# Change WooCommerce Weight field to accept letters

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

How do I change the WooCommerce Shipping weight field to accept letters so that I can put values such as:

> 500g / 1kg / 750ml / 2L

There is no use for the weight other than to display the mass, no shipping is required.

I've searched through the WooCommerce files but I can't find where it's set. Can someone point me to the file that controls this field?

Comment: Cleaned up question and reduced scope to be on-topic

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the issue with a work around. I simply removed the restriction for the weight to include letters eg below

```
//remove decimal only

add_action( 'wc_product_weight_enabled', 'remove_decimal_only' );

function remove_decimal_only() {
  woocommerce_wp_text_input( array( 'id' => '_weight', 'label' => __( 'Weight', 'woocommerce' ) . ' (' . get_option( 'woocommerce_weight_unit' ) . ')', 'placeholder' => wc_format_localized_decimal( 0 ), 'desc_tip' => 'true', 'description' => __( 'Enter weight including unit', 'woocommerce' ), 'type' => 'text' ) );

}
```

I didn't know how to use the add action and filters originally but now they're pretty simple.

The file was located in woocommerce/includes/admin/meta-boxes/class-wc-meta-box-product-data.php